# Data Structure not returning expected result

Tags: java, data-structures

I am working on a budgeting tool, and in order to do that, I am creating my own linked list that stores details on each income type. The issue that I am having, is when I try to call the pay for a job, it returns 0.

```
public class IncomeNode{
    Node head; 
    int size;  

public IncomeNode(){
head = null; 
size = 0;  
}



    class Node{
        double amount; 
        String jobName; 
        Node next; 

        Node(String name, double number){
            jobName = name; 
            amount = number; 
        }
        
        Node(){
            jobName = "";
            amount = 0;
        }
    }

public void add(String name, double number){
    Node newIncome = new Node(name, number); 
    if(head == null){
        head = newIncome; 
    }
    else{
        Node current = head; 
        while(current.next != null){
            current = current.next; 
        }
        current.next = newIncome;
    }
    size++; 
}

public double getPay(String job){
    Node current = head; 
    while(current.next !=null){
       
        if(current.jobName.equals(job)){
            return current.amount;
        }
        current = current.next; 
 
    }
   return 0;
    
}
    }
```

I added a get method that should iterate through the linked list and pull the pay information for the job that matches the name input by the user. Instead, skipping a section of my code and resulting 0.

This is the code in my main method that calls this method.

```
Class Budget{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean newJob = true; 

 if(payType.equals("variable")){
                System.out.print("What is your hourly pay?"); 
                double wage = scnr.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("How many hours do you work a week?");
                double hours = scnr.nextDouble();
                IncomeNode jobs = new IncomeNode();

                jobs.add(name, wage * hours);

                System.out.println(jobs.getPay(name));
            System.out.print("Do you want to add another income?"); 
            if(scnr.next().equals("no")){
                newJob = false;
            }

            }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?  And I'm not sure the finance or adwords-budgetservice tags are relevant (add a language tag though).

Comment: Tangential: Why did you need your own linked list?

Comment: Please remember to post code that people can easily read: [edit] your post and then replace the code blocks with properly indented code. Just tell your IDE to auto-format it, and then put that in your post. That's what the auto-formatter if for: to make your code easy to read (both for other people, and future you)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your `getPay` method might be related to the fact that you are using `while(current.next != null)` as the loop condition. This causes you to iterate through all nodes except the last one. Therefore, when you reach the last node, its `next` will be null, which will terminate the loop without examining the content of the last node.

To solve this issue, you can change the loop condition to `while(current != null)`. Additionally, you might want to add handling for the case where you don't find a matching job, by returning a default value (e.g. -1) or throwing an exception to indicate that the job is not present.

Here is the corrected version of your getPay method:

```
public double getPay(String job) {
        Node current = head;
    
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.jobName.equals(job)) {
                return current.amount;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    
        // If the job is not found, you can return a default value or throw an exception.
        // Here, I return -1 as a signal for "not found".
        return -1;

        }
```

Let me knwon if this solved the problem, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I see what's happening in your `getPay` method. It's a classic case of missing the last stop on a train journey! Right now, your method is like checking every station except the last one. When your code looks for a job's pay, it stops checking just before the last job in your list.

The culprit is the line `while(current.next != null)`. This line tells your program to stop looking if the next station (or job, in your case) is the end of the line. But what if the job you're looking for is the last one? Well, it gets skipped.

To fix this, just tweak that line to `while(current != null)`. This way, your program will check every job in the list, including the very last one. It's like making sure you check the last station too, just in case that's where your job (or treasure, if we stick with the journey metaphor) is hiding.

With this small change, your code should happily find any job's pay, whether it's the first, middle, or last in your list.

```
public double getPay(String job){
    Node current = head; 
    while(current != null){ // Changed from current.next != null to current != null
       
        if(current.jobName.equals(job)){
            return current.amount;
        }
        current = current.next; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```